# What are the exact steps for documenting an express API using swagger-jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, swagger

I want to document my express router endpoint using the swagger-jsdoc from NPM.
I've never user swagger and I want to know the exact steps to write it in my code and how eventually i'll be able to generate a YAML/JSON documentation file.

```
router.post('/docToSafe', (req, res, next) => {

  let SafeProperties = req.body.SafeProperties;
  let DocumentsArray = req.body.Documents;


  if ((SafeProperties.PathToSafe) && (SafeProperties.ZipName) && (DocumentsArray[0].DocID)) {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end();

  }

  else {

    res.writeHead(500, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end();

  }
}
```

Comment: Checkout this example repo - https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/tree/master/example